# How to Update Larapex Charts Data (with Laravel)

Tags: laravel, filter, charts

I want to update the Larapex chart data when the user selects a filter. Here is my code:

Route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard/absence-chart/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'reloadChart'])->name('sendId-unit');
```

AbsensiChart.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Charts;

use App\Models\Absence;
use App\Models\DataKelas;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use ArielMejiaDev\LarapexCharts\LarapexChart;
use Illuminate\Console\View\Components\Alert;

class AbsensiChart
{
    protected $chart, $id;

    public function __construct(LarapexChart $chart)
    {
        $this->chart = $chart;
    }

    public function setUnitId($id = null) {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function build(): \ArielMejiaDev\LarapexCharts\LineChart
    {   
        $kelas = DataKelas::orderBy('kelas', 'ASC');

        if ($this->id !== null) {
            $kelas->where('unit_id', $this->id);
        }

        $kelas = $kelas->get();
        
        $absensi = Absence::class; 

        foreach ($kelas as $kelas) {
            $data_hadir[] = $absensi::with('data_kelas')->select('kelas_id')->whereHas('data_kelas', function ($query) use ($kelas) {
                $query->where('kelas', $kelas->kelas);
            })->where('absensi', 'Hadir')->groupBy('kelas_id')->count();

            $data_sakit[] = $absensi::with('data_kelas')->select('kelas_id')->whereHas('data_kelas', function ($query) use ($kelas) {
                $query->where('kelas', $kelas->kelas);
            })->where('absensi', 'Sakit')->groupBy('kelas_id')->count();

            $data_izin[] = $absensi::with('data_kelas')->select('kelas_id')->whereHas('data_kelas', function ($query) use ($kelas) {
                $query->where('kelas', $kelas->kelas);
            })->where('absensi', 'Ijin')->groupBy('kelas_id')->count();

            $data_lainnya[] = $absensi::with('data_kelas')->select('kelas_id')->whereHas('data_kelas', function ($query) use ($kelas) {
                $query->where('kelas', $kelas->kelas);
            })->where('absensi', 'Lainnya')->groupBy('kelas_id')->count();

            $label_x[] = "Kelas ".$kelas->kelas;
        }

        return $this->chart->lineChart()
                ->setHeight(350)
                ->addData('Jumlah Hadir', $data_hadir)
                ->addData('Jumlah Sakit', $data_sakit)
                ->addData('Jumlah Izin', $data_izin)
                ->addData('Jumlah Lainnya', $data_lainnya)
                ->setXAxis($label_x);
    }
}
```

AdminController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Teacher;
use App\Models\Employee;
use App\Models\DataKelas;
use App\Models\DataSiswa;
use App\Charts\AbsensiChart;
use App\Models\ParameterUnit;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use ArielMejiaDev\LarapexCharts\Facades\LarapexChart;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index(AbsensiChart $absensiChart)
    {
        $jumlah_siswa = DataSiswa::count();
        $jumlah_guru = Teacher::count();
        $jumlah_karyawan = Employee::count();
        $jumlah_user = User::count();
        $units = ParameterUnit::all();

        return view('dashboard.index',[
            'absensiChart' => $absensiChart->build(),
            'units' => $units,
            'jumlah_siswa' => $jumlah_siswa,
            'jumlah_guru' => $jumlah_guru,
            'jumlah_karyawan' => $jumlah_karyawan,
            'jumlah_user' => $jumlah_user,
            "title" => "Halaman Admin"
        ]);
    }

    public function reloadChart(AbsensiChart $absensiChart, $id)
    {
        $chartData = $absensiChart->setUnitId($id)->build();
        
        return response()->json(['chartData' => $chartData]);
    }
}
```

Script to process Larapex chart data:

```
    <script src="{{ $absensiChart->cdn() }}"></script>
    {{ $absensiChart->script() }}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#unit_id').on('change', function() {
                var unit_id = $(this).val();
                if (unit_id != null) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/admin/dashboard/absence-chart/' + unit_id,
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: {
                            '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                        },
                        success: function(response){
                            response.chartData->updateSeries([
                                ['name' => 'Jumlah Hadir', 'data' => $data_hadir],
                                ['name' => 'Jumlah Sakit', 'data' => $data_sakit],
                                ['name' => 'Jumlah Izin', 'data' => $data_izin],
                                ['name' => 'Jumlah Lainnya', 'data' => $data_lainnya],
                            ]);

                            $chartData->script();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
         });
    </script>
```

to show larapex chart in blade.php:

```
      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                    <h4 class="card-title mb-0">Statistik Absensi Harian</h4>
                                    <div class="d-flex ms-auto w-50">
                                        <input type="date" id="tanggal" name="tanggal" class="form-control me-3">
                                        <select name="unit_id" id="unit_id" class="form-select w-30">
                                            <option selected value="">Pilih Unit</option>
                                            @foreach ($units as $unit)
                                                <option value="{{ $unit->id }}">{{ $unit->nama_unit }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown sub-dropdown">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link text-muted dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                            id="dd1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                            aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i data-feather="more-vertical"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dd1">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.absence-view') }}">Absensi Harian</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.absence-recap-view') }}">Absensi Rekap</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                          
                            </div>
                            <div class="pl-4 mb-5">
                                <div class="stats ct-charts position-relative" style="height: 315px;">
                                    {!! $absensiChart->container() !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The results:

[image]

With the provided code, when I select a filter (unit) and retrieve the unit filter's value, I then use it in the URL: '/admin/dashboard/absence-chart/' + unit_id (via an AJAX request). Subsequently, I use this value (id) in the reloadChart method in the AdminController. I wish to be able to use this id to fetch data based on it through method chaining: $chartData = $absensiChart->setUnitId($id)->build(); (In AbsensiChart.php, I call the setUnitId() method and wish to use the id in the build() method to process Larapex chart data based on that id). In the reloadChart method, I return it as JSON and attempt to update the Larapex chart data with:

```
$response->chartData->updateSeries([
    ['name' => 'Jumlah Hadir', 'data' => $data_hadir],
    ['name' => 'Jumlah Sakit', 'data' => $data_sakit],
    ['name' => 'Jumlah Izin', 'data' => $data_izin],
    ['name' => 'Jumlah Lainnya', 'data' => $data_lainnya],
]);

$chartData->script();
```

However, this is not working. Is there a specific way in Larapex chart to achieve this? I've just tried it. Thank you in advance.